# How do I update my git password on linux?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, passwords

For some reason I set my git password on my Ubuntu desktop to something different than what I have it set to on my Windows laptop and I'd like to change the password on linux. Everything I'm finding talks about a credential helper but that's not really what I want. I don't mind typing in my password because it helps me to remember it. I have the current password so I'm not locked out but I can't find how to simply update the password. If I store the password in the credential helper and then something happens down the road where I need to enter that password I wouldn't remember it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't set a credential helper, and `origin` in the repository is `http://` or `https://` (or maybe `ftp://`), and the remote repository requires authentication, Git will ask you for the username and the password after you run `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push`. If you want to manually type in every time, remove `credential.helper` from all gitconfigs. You can use `git config --show-origin credential.helper` to check whether and where it's set. `--show -origin` may be not valid, if your Git is too old.

Comment: Does [this Git FAQ entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager) answer your question?

Comment: Is this password the pass to an ssh key ? What commands do you use when you have to type this password ?

Comment: LeGEC You know, I think it is the ssh passphrase. It happens when I do a git pull. That would explain why I couldn't find the answer, my initial assumption was wrong. I was tired and should've called it a day a little earlier. Thanks!